# How to hide if condition in customize template in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I want to generate customize template to generate getter and setter method depending upon the dataType.

```
eg. if dataType is date then :

    if(${return_type} == Date){
     return ${field} != null ? new Date(${field}.getTime()) : null;
    }
```